# OpenTypeSelectionDialog cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Why do I get this error "OpenTypeSelectionDialog cannot be resolved to a type" when I am trying to use OpenTypeSelectionDialog in my code?

Here's the code:

```
 Shell sParent = JavaPlugin.getActiveWorkbenchShell();
 SelectionDialog dialog = new OpenTypeSelectionDialog(sParent, true,
          PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getProgressService(),null, IJavaSearchConstants.TYPE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error when compiler is not able to find file/class containing code for specified Java class. 
There are a number of places where Types can be included,
1. Have you imported the Type for which you are getting error.
2. You also might have specified the wrong place (by a misspelling, perhaps)
3. You might want to check if library containing missing Type is not included in classpath.

Check if you are able to locate the class file?

Comment: Thanks. That was quite helpful

Answer (score 1):

you should open your plugin.xml file in your project, dependencies tab and add org.eclipse.jdt.ui as plugin dependency, after that organize imports and you should be OK.